# Which function should I define as live and how would I do it without click event?

Tags: jquery

I have a refresh function that is set to refresh on a time interval. There is a function within that function called scrollTo which scrolls to the last element of the box. The problem is that elements are constantly being added to the box so without the use of 'live' the scrollTo will find a div and stick to it instead of finding the new last-child and scrolling to it on refresh. Which function should I apply live to, the refresh() or the ScrollTo and I always see live with a click event, can you attach it in a different way?

```
  function refresh() {

$.scrollTo('div[chunk_id="'+autoscroll+'"] > :last-child', 800, {easing:'elasout',offset:-250} );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would this do the same?:

```
function refresh() {
  var div = $('div[chunk_id="'+autoscroll+'"] > :last-child');

  $.scrollTo(div, 800, {easing:'elasout',offset:-250} );
}
```

I don't think it will since you are explicitly creating a scoped variable.  It should recalculate that value on each run of the function.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it does do the same thing. Does not recalculate div.

Comment: I think there is some other problem with your code then.  I just tested dynamically creating a div and appending it to an existing div and the code $("div#test > :last-child") properly returns the new div every time.  Perhaps the issue is with your "autoscroll" variable?

Comment: alternatively, try $('div[chunk_id="'+autoscroll+'"] > :last') which is designed to return only a single jquery element rather than potentially an array of elements, which is what you may be getting back instead.

I'm pretty sure that if $.scrollTo gets an array of jquery objects as the target that it will just pick the first one.